# Need help to implement a Spinner into my RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, spinner

I'm trying to sort my `RecyclerView` with a `Spinner`. Every item in the List contains 1 `ImageView` and 2 `TextView` components. Would be a pleasure if somebody could implement the `Spinner` to my code, that I can sort those items.

I tried to implement the spinner twice, but needed to rebuild to recycler view without the spinner, because I failed. Don't know how to set up recycler view and spinner together, even with tutorials... I am stuck.

My Item.xml Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="@color/Green">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/SupItemIV1"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/SupItemTV1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="160dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="CREATINE"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/SupItemTV2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="amino acid"
            android:textColor="@color/GreyDark"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

My MainActivity (Here Supplements.java class):

```
package com.example.etigym;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Supplements extends AppCompatActivity{

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_supplements);

        ArrayList<SupplementsItem> supplementsList = new ArrayList<>();
        supplementsList.add(new SupplementsItem(R.drawable.creatine, "CREATINE", "amino acid"));
        supplementsList.add(new SupplementsItem(R.drawable.glutamine, "GLUTAMINE", "amino acid"));
        supplementsList.add(new SupplementsItem(R.drawable.leucine, "LEUCINE", "amino acid"));
        supplementsList.add(new SupplementsItem(R.drawable.valine, "VALINE", "amino acid"));
        supplementsList.add(new SupplementsItem(R.drawable.isoleucine, "ISOLEUCINE", "amino acid"));
        supplementsList.add(new SupplementsItem(R.drawable.alanine, "ALANINE", "amino acid"));
        supplementsList.add(new SupplementsItem(R.drawable.arginine, "ARGININE", "amino acid"));

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.Supplements_RV);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mAdapter = new SupplementsAdapter(supplementsList);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(mRecyclerView, false);

    }
}
```

My Supplements Layout from the Supplements.java class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Supplements">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/Supplements_RV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:background="@color/GreyDark"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Adapter:

```
public class SupplementsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SupplementsAdapter.SupplementsViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<SupplementsItem> mSupplementsList;

    public static class SupplementsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public ImageView mImageView;
        public TextView mTextView1;
        public TextView mTextView2;

        public SupplementsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.SupItemIV1);
            mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.SupItemTV1);
            mTextView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.SupItemTV2);
        }
    }

    public SupplementsAdapter(ArrayList<SupplementsItem> supplementsList){
        mSupplementsList = supplementsList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SupplementsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.supplements_item, parent, false);
        SupplementsViewHolder svh = new SupplementsViewHolder(v);
        return svh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SupplementsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        SupplementsItem currentSupplementsItem = mSupplementsList.get(position);

        holder.mImageView.setImageResource(currentSupplementsItem.getImageResource());
        holder.mTextView1.setText(currentSupplementsItem.getText1());
        holder.mTextView2.setText(currentSupplementsItem.getText2());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mSupplementsList.size();
    }
}
```

SupplementsItem.java:

```
package com.example.etigym;

public class SupplementsItem {
    private int mImageResource;
    private String mText1;
    private String mText2;

    public SupplementsItem(int imageResource, String text1, String text2){
        mImageResource = imageResource;
        mText1 = text1;
        mText2 = text2;
    }

    public int getImageResource(){
        return mImageResource;
    }

    public String getText1(){
        return mText1;
    }

    public String getText2(){
        return mText2;
    }
}
```

Afterwards we should have a List which we can sort by categories.

Comment: Not really clear to me what you want to achieve with the spinner. Do you want to sort your `recyclerView` using a control from a spinner or you just want a way to sort your `recyclerView` perhaps without the spinner?

Comment: Hello Racu, thanks for replying! I want to use the Spinner as Top Header where I can choose options. For instants categories in Spinner: "Amino Acids, Vitamins etc.. So if I choose Amino Acids in the Spinner, the RecyclerView should display only all Amino Acids. That would be nice!

Comment: Where are your stuck? in the sorting of the `recyclerView` or the spinner implementation. I think you might want to solve one over the other first and then move to the next. And in this case you want to sort the sorting part first.

Comment: I have problems with the implementation of the Spinner and later on with "OnItemSelectedListener" part. I have no clue how to integrate a spinner with my code and especially with my Items as a cardview. If you could add a spinner to my code and making items response and sort to the selected categories in the Spinner, that would mean the world to me! Stucking hours and hours to solve this problem :/

Comment: But you already know how to sort the items?

Comment: Yes kinda, with if and else statements in the OnItemSelectedListener section.

Comment: Please add your `SupplementsItem` class, then I'll post you an answer on how to sort the items. Then you can ask a question about the spinner alone and I'll do my best to help you ;-)

Comment: I did add it, thank you so much for your help! I'm excited how you will set up the sort function. That's how it should look like, but with my Items and with the RecyclerView instead of the ListView: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_N8amiRtGSQ

Comment: Last question, what is in general a "Creatine" and "amino acid" just to rename the parameters accordingly, your `mText1` and `mText2` is not what you are after ;-)

Comment: "Creatine" is the Item, like Valine, Isoleucine etc.. The category for the Spinner should be: Amino Acids, Vitamins etc.. But I see: The mText1 is the name of the Item in the cardview, which you can click later on. The mText2 is just a little headline underneath.

Comment: Hier is a screenshot of the recyclerview in the app: https://ibb.co/ns9r7Xm mText1 is The Head Name "Creatine" and mText2 is the subtext to declare the product a bit. And now I will sort this as I mentioned

Comment: In general terms you want to name your variables with meaningful names, in 2 years when you get back to your code you'll be scratching your head trying to figure out what `mText1` is supposed to address, look at my answer as an example not what you have to do. If it solves your issue with the sorting part please check it as solved, from there you shall have an easier path to implement your spinner or make another question, post the link here and I'll see what I can do to help you out ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much, now I can sort my Items by categories! The Spinner should display the categories later on. I will post a new link to "How to implement the sort in RecyclerView with a Spinner". Will link it then. Sharing is caring, so you deserved your reputations! Hope you will help me further on then :)

Comment: I really think that you'll find out by yourself, if stuck just post relevant code on what you have done with the spinner and sure will try to help, best regards.

Comment: Hello Racu, where do I put this `private void sortByCategoryDown(){ Collections.sort(mSupplementsList, new SupplementsItem.CategoryComparatorDown());
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }` at? In `SupplementsAdapter.java` or in the `Supplements.java`?

Comment: In the class you are going to call it, in this case I think should be `Suplements.java` and you call it from your spinner `onItemSelected`

Comment: The problem is, that it don't find the `mSupplementList`, because the declaration is in my `AdapterSupplements.java`. How can I link this to the `Supplements.java` class? Sorry I'm pretty new in coding but try to push through! ;D

Comment: `supplementsList`, sorry I added the 'm' at the beginning

Comment: Nice! Just edited your code, for correction.

Comment: I don't think that edit was necessary, but is ok, however to be consistent you should edit the whole `SuplementsItem` item class that I provided in my answer as an example, to match your coding style, which I think is beyond the scope of the question. All cool.

Comment: So sorry, I forgot that you get minus reputation. Totally dumb of mine. Sorry! I just try to implement the `Spinner` right now. I try to make some categories shown up as `Strings` in the `Spinner`. When I have done that, it would be a pleasure, when you help me out to connect the values (string categories) from the `Spinner` to the sorting stuff, we did so far.

Comment: Hey Racu my friend, how can I access this variable (shown in screenshot). I think I set up the `Spinner` right so far. What do you think? https://ibb.co/NTS8Pkq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to know how to sort the items on the list according to your needs, to do that you have to create a class that implements `Comparator` usually you want to do this class(es) within your Model Class `SupplementsItem`, this is how it could look your `SupplementsItem`, note that I added an extra property `expiryDate`, the idea is that you understand how to use the comparator to sort your list.

```
public class SupplementsItem {
    private int itemImage;
    private String item;
    private String category;
    private long expiryDate;

    public SupplementsItem(int itemImage, String item, String category, long expiryDate) {
        this.itemImage = itemImage;
        this.item = item;
        this.category = category;
        this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
    }

    public int getItemImage() {
        return itemImage;
    }

    public void setItemImage(int itemImage) {
        this.itemImage = itemImage;
    }

    public String getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public long getExpiryDate() {
        return expiryDate;
    }

    public void setExpiryDate(long expiryDate) {
        this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
    }

    //    This will sort your list ascending by category
    public static class CategoryComparatorUp implements Comparator<SupplementsItem> {
        @Override
        public int compare(SupplementsItem o1, SupplementsItem o2) {
            return o1.getCategory().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getCategory());
        }
    }

    //    This will sort your list descending by category
    public static class CategoryComparatorDown implements Comparator<SupplementsItem> {
        @Override
        public int compare(SupplementsItem o1, SupplementsItem o2) {
            return o2.getCategory().compareToIgnoreCase(o1.getCategory());
        }
    }

    //    This will sort your list ascending by expiration date
    public static class ExpiryComparatorUp implements Comparator<SupplementsItem> {
        @Override
        public int compare(SupplementsItem o1, SupplementsItem o2) {
            return Long.compare(o1.getExpiryDate(), o2.getExpiryDate());
        }
    }

    //    This will sort your list descending by expiration date
    public static class ExpiryComparatorDown implements Comparator<SupplementsItem> {
        @Override
        public int compare(SupplementsItem o1, SupplementsItem o2) {
            return Long.compare(o2.getExpiryDate(), o1.getExpiryDate());
        }
    }
}
```

I have placed 4 comparators but you really need only one by category, or make a more complex comparator.

For example if you want to sort by Expiration date descending you want to use `ExpiryComparatorUp` and then `Collections.reverse()`, like this you can use only one comparator by property in your model.

To use it after you populate your list, you call:

```
 Collections.sort(supplementsList, new SupplementsItem.CategoryComparatorDown());
```

followed by:

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

or you can create a method for each type of sorting you want to do, i.e.:

```
   private void sortByCategoryDown() {
        Collections.sort(supplementsList, new SupplementsItem.CategoryComparatorDown());
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

and then in your onItemSelected of your spinner just call `sortByCategoryDown()`

From here you only need to work in your spinner logic. Let me know of your doubts in the comments.
I modified your class with the idea of giving you an idea on how to do the `Comparator` thingy, but you don't need to make it like that.